# Having trouble sharing codestyle through source control for Android projects (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have committed a codestyle for a project in `.idea/codeStyles/Project.xml`. It works as expected on my machine.

When I clone this project with this codestyle changes **on another machine, Android Studio IDE overrides the file (Project.xml)**.

I want to share this same codestyle across the team using a project-level codestyle configuration using source control and not by manually setting the codestyle for the project by importing it through the settings.

I couldn't really figure out a way to get this done.

Product version:

Android Studio 3.0.1 Build #AI-171.4443003, built on November 9, 2017 JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b08 x86_64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o Mac OS X 10.13.1